# What is the topology on the direct limit of $\Bbb R^i \rightarrow \Bbb R^j$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If we let $X$ be direct limit of 
$$\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \cdots $$ 
where each arrow is inclusion to first coordinates.

What is a choice of $X$ (with a toplogy that coincides with the direct limit topology).

EDIT: I believe it is subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, sequence eventually $0$  taking values in $\Bbb R$, with the **product topology**.  I wonder if this is correct.

Comment: The direct limit is the set of sequences which are eventually zero.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is right. But how about the topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the direct limit is

$$L=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\ |\ x_i=0\text{ eventually}\}$$

The direct limit topology on $L$ is the topology [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology) with $\{\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ treated as subspaces of $L$ via obvious inclusions.

There's another natural choice for topology on $L$: the one induced by the Euclidean norm (note that the Euclidean norm is well defined on sequences that are eventually $0$).

I remember my surprise when I learned that these two are not the same. The example is as follows: let $v_i$ be a vector with $1/i$ on the $i$-th position and $0$ elsewhere. Then $E=\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is closed in the direct limit (because $E\cap\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite for any $n$) but not closed in the Euclidean norm (because $\lVert v_i\rVert=1/i$ and so the sequence converges to $0$).

In fact it can be shown that [the direct limit is not metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356085/inductive-limit-topology-and-first-countability). In particular this also means that $L$ is not a subspace (even up to homeomorphism) of the product topology (at least a product of metrizable spaces) because [countable product of metrizable spaces is metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361778/show-that-the-countable-product-of-metric-spaces-is-metrizable).

Comment: I wonder what happens if you use the topology where the closed sets are either the full space, or else (images of) closed subsets of some $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It seems like that would be the smallest topology that makes each $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the subspace topology be the Euclidean topology.